# iPhone Datepicker.date is 4 hours and 56 minutes fast, help?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker

Hey all so as the title suggest I just have a date picker and it appears to be 4 hours and 56 minutes fast.. which is very strange. Code is very straight foreword:

```
NSLog(@"%@",datePicker.date);
```

In the view did load

```
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

ETA: for example if I set the time as 4 00 PM I get this in the NSLog

```
0001-01-01 20:56:02 +0000
```

Comment: In which time zone do you live?

Comment: I live on the East Coast, my iPhone is set to New York.

Comment: Okay, you live -4 Hours from UTC and wonder why your time is +4 Hours when presented in UTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `minimumDate` and `maximumDate` on your date picker to something sane.

Dates before October 1582 tend to have numerous issues in iOS, due to some things recognizing the Julian/Gregorian calendar transition and other things not. There also seems to be accuracy issues in the times when you deal NSDates near the year 1.

Comment: huh, when I set a minimum and maximum dates in IB it crashes my app with a NSRanceExcpeption... The years were 1970 and 2020 edit: fixed that, old data was saved in NSUserdefaut

Comment: @bipolarpants: Remember that NSDate's `description` prints times in UTC. Which is 4 hours later than your local time, if your device is set to America/New York.